# Cómo hacer funcionar en iOS el Progress Indicator External Object?

Tags: genexus

Tenemos un Panel SD, dentro del cual al relizar ciertas acciones (presionar botones, activar/desactivar un switch) hemos utilizado
el Progress Indicator external object para mostrar por pantalla un mensaje mientras procesa.

```
GeneXus.Common.UI.Progress.Title = "Procesando"

GeneXus.Common.UI.Progress.Description = "Guardando datos..."

GeneXus.Common.UI.Progress.Class = "Table.Progress"

GeneXus.Common.UI.Progress.Type = ProgressIndicatorType.Indeterminate
   
GeneXus.Common.UI.Progress.Show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Android nos funciona perfecto!: muestra la ventana temporal con el Spinning Wheel.
Pero en iOS lo estamos probando y no muestra ninguna ventana.
Estamos trabajando con **Genexus 17 Upgrade 6**, y por otro lado con **XCode 13.1**, y utilizando **emulador IPhone X**
Qué nos faltaría parametrizar o realizar para que funcione en iOS?

En el link
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19338,HowTo%3A+Using+Progress+Indicator+in+Smart+Devices
hay un ejemplo en un emulador IPhone X, pero no encontramos diferencia entre la lógica del ejemplo y como lo utilizamos en nuestro Panel SD.

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier orientación ó tip.

Comment: Parece estar bien el codigo del "show" que mostras, aunque falta informacion, podrias subir el evento completo? Ademas, podrias ver si te salta algun error en la consola del xcode activando el log con la propiedad: "Log level = debug" en el main de tu app a ver si da alguna info extra.

Comment: @Chona he incluido en la logica la funcion sleep(1) para detener un segundo la ejecucion y de este modo en iOS muestra el cartel del Progress Indicator. Como que en Android lo muestra siempre pero en iOS necesita esa pausa forzada. Cuando se trabaja con 1 Panel SD con multiples Layout ví que hay una sola solapa de Events sin importar la plataforma. Cómo se podria  preguntar en Events para que ejecute una logica u otra segun la plataforma?

Comment: Para eso tenes que usar el ClientInformation y preguntar por el OSName. Te dejo mas info en este link: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31271,ClientInformation%20external%20object